# How can I use the gradle idea task to set Intellij's default settings?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How can I use the gradle idea task to set values in Intellij's default.xml file?

Background: I'm creating a tool to reconfigure Intellij, and some users will be using the IDE's global configuration, and other will be using the project's configuration, so I need to change both of them. The global configuration is stored in the default.xml file, and the project settings are stored in the projects ipr file.

I can make the necessary changes to the ipr file, but not the default.xml file.

Comment: What default.xml file do you mean exactly? Personally I do not know of it is possible to use Gradle [idea plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) to change any IDE's default configurations.

Comment: The default.xml in Intellij's config/codestyles/ folder. And I think it isn't possible.

Comment: Close voter, mind explaining what you think is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin which generates IDEA project configuration and allows you to modify it [Gradle IDEA Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html).

Set JDK and language level:

```
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'idea'

 idea {
   project {
     jdkName = '1.6'
     languageLevel = '1.5'
   }
 }
```

The project files will be generated, when you run the `idea` task: `gradle idea`.

The only one catch: the plugin does not support the IDEA directory based [project configuration layout](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#project-formats), only the file based.